# (React) How to get the state of another component when a submit button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have 3 files, and they are as follows:

**App.js**

```
import MP3Options from './mp3'
import SubmitButton from './submit'

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {codec: "MP3"};
  
  onCodecChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({codec: e.target.value})
  }

  submitClicked() {
    console.log('Submit button was clicked.')
  }

  renderComponent = () => {
    const { codec } = this.state;
    switch (codec) {
      case 'MP3':
        return  <MP3Options />
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // Codec options div.
      <div>
        <select id="codecs" onChange={this.onCodecChange} value={this.state.codec}>
          <option value="AAC">AAC (.m4a)</option>
          <option value="AC3">AC3 (Dolby Digital)</option>
          <option value="ALAC">ALAC</option>
          <option value="CAF">CAF (.caf)</option>
          <option value="DTS">DTS</option>
          <option value="FLAC">FLAC</option>
          <option value="MKA">MKA (extract audio without encoding it)</option>
          <option value="MKV">MKV (.mkv)</option>
          <option value="MP3">MP3</option>
          <option value="MP4">MP4 (.mp4)</option>
          <option value="Opus">Opus (.opus)</option>
          <option value="Vorbis">Vorbis (.ogg)</option>
          <option value="WAV">WAV</option>
        </select>
        {this.renderComponent()}
        <SubmitButton onSubmit={this.submitClicked} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**mp3.js**

```
import Mp3Cbr from './Mp3Cbr'
import Mp3Vbr from './Mp3Vbr'

class MP3Options extends React.Component {
    state = {mp3EncodingType: 'cbr'};

    onMp3EncodingTypeChange = event => {
        this.setState({mp3EncodingType: event.target.value});
    }

    renderComponent = () => {
        const { mp3EncodingType } = this.state
        switch (mp3EncodingType) {
            // Show the Mp3Cbr component if CBR or ABR is selected. Show the Mp3Vbr component if VBR is selected.
            case 'cbr':
            return <Mp3Cbr />;;
            case 'abr':
            return <Mp3Cbr />;
            case 'vbr':
            return <Mp3Vbr />;
            default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div id="mp3_encoding_div">
            <label htmlFor="mp3_encoding_type">Encoding Type:</label>
            <select id="mp3_encoding_type" onChange={this.onMp3EncodingTypeChange} value={this.state.mp3EncodingType}>
                <option disabled value>Select encoding type</option>
                <option value="cbr">CBR (Constant Bitrate)</option>
                <option value="abr">ABR (Average Bitrate)</option>
                <option value="vbr">VBR (Variable Bitrate)</option>
            </select>
            {this.renderComponent()}
        </div>
        );
    }
}
    
export default MP3Options;
```

**submit.js**

```
class SubmitButton extends React.Component {

    submitClicked = () => {
        this.props.onSubmit();
    }

    render () {
        return (
        <button id="convert_btn" onClick={this.submitClicked}>Submit</button>
        )
    }
}
export default SubmitButton;
```

In App.js, I am able to detect when the submit button is clicked (the submitClicked() function gets triggered). What I want now is, in App.js, I want to get the value of the JSX select element in mp3.js (i.e. whether the value is cbr, abr or vbr). How do I do this? I'm guessing you need to do props related things but I'm having a little bit of trouble wrapping my head around these new concepts as I'm new to react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should manage state and event callback of `Mp3Options` component in `App.js`, and pass them as props to `Mp3Options` component. Please check below for detail.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import MP3Options from './mp3';
import SubmitButton from './submit';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { codec: 'MP3', mp3EncodingType: 'cbr' };

  onCodecChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ codec: e.target.value });
  };

  onMp3EncodingTypeChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ mp3EncodingType: event.target.value });
  };

  submitClicked = () => {
    console.log('Submit button was clicked.');
    console.log(this.state.mp3EncodingType);
  };

  renderComponent = () => {
    const { codec, mp3EncodingType } = this.state;
    switch (codec) {
      case 'MP3':
        return (
          <MP3Options
            mp3EncodingType={mp3EncodingType}
            onChange={this.onMp3EncodingTypeChange}
          />
        );
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      // Codec options div.
      <div>
        <select
          id="codecs"
          onChange={this.onCodecChange}
          value={this.state.codec}
        >
          <option value="AAC">AAC (.m4a)</option>
          <option value="AC3">AC3 (Dolby Digital)</option>
          <option value="ALAC">ALAC</option>
          <option value="CAF">CAF (.caf)</option>
          <option value="DTS">DTS</option>
          <option value="FLAC">FLAC</option>
          <option value="MKA">MKA (extract audio without encoding it)</option>
          <option value="MKV">MKV (.mkv)</option>
          <option value="MP3">MP3</option>
          <option value="MP4">MP4 (.mp4)</option>
          <option value="Opus">Opus (.opus)</option>
          <option value="Vorbis">Vorbis (.ogg)</option>
          <option value="WAV">WAV</option>
        </select>
        {this.renderComponent()}
        <SubmitButton onSubmit={this.submitClicked} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**mp3.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Mp3Cbr from './Mp3Cbr';
import Mp3Vbr from './Mp3Vbr';

class MP3Options extends React.Component {
  renderComponent = () => {
    const { mp3EncodingType } = this.props;
    switch (mp3EncodingType) {
      // Show the Mp3Cbr component if CBR or ABR is selected. Show the Mp3Vbr component if VBR is selected.
      case 'cbr':
        return <Mp3Cbr />;
      case 'abr':
        return <Mp3Cbr />;
      case 'vbr':
        return <Mp3Vbr />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    return (
      <div id="mp3_encoding_div">
        <label htmlFor="mp3_encoding_type">Encoding Type:</label>
        <select id="mp3_encoding_type" onChange={onChange}>
          <option disabled value>
            Select encoding type
          </option>
          <option value="cbr">CBR (Constant Bitrate)</option>
          <option value="abr">ABR (Average Bitrate)</option>
          <option value="vbr">VBR (Variable Bitrate)</option>
        </select>
        {this.renderComponent()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MP3Options;
```

Comment: I'm laying in bed so I will test this when I wake up. It's only the states that need to be managed in App.js, right? If so, I'm guessing it's okay to put the onMp3EncodingTypeChange function in mp3.js instead? Thanks for the help, I will try your code when I wake up.

Comment: if you put it inside mp3.js, you should need another callback function in mp3.js to change the state value in App.js

Comment: Hmm, I'll have a play about with both options. As a side note, I've only added the mp3 components so far but eventually the states object thing in App.js is going to be much bigger as I need to create components for all of the other codecs that you can see in the codecs div and manage their states in App.js. This is partly why I think it may be better to put the callback functions in the components themselves otherwise App.js may start to look a little confusing. I appreciate your help and I will mark your answer as correct when I have verified that it works :)

Comment: In App.js, for `console.log(this.state.mp3EncodingType);` I'm getting "Cannot read property 'mp3EncodingType' of undefined"

Comment: Ah, you should bind `submitClicked()` function or use arrow function to use same context.

Comment: I've just updated my answer. check that it is canged to `submitClicked = () => {}`

Comment: Nothing is being logged for `console.log(this.state.mp3EncodingType)`. Also, when I change the option for the CBR/ABR/VBR dropdown menu, when I select VBR it's not showing the `<Mp3Vbr />;` component so something must be wrong in the switch `switch (mp3EncodingType) {` section of mp3.js. Btw, `value={mp3EncodingType}` should be set to the options not the select element itself, but I have already changed that.

Comment: so did you fix all? if not can you upload your code to codesandbox?

Comment: Here's the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-bush-wg3ks?file=/src/App.js
I've tried to fix these issues but I can't. I appreciate your help so far and I hope you can figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Please find the sandbox above. Also, I was wrong about the console.log not showing anything. The issue is that it always logs "cbr" no matter which option I choose. Also, when I choose VBR, the `<Mp3Vbr />;` component doesn't show.

Comment: I've updated code with working solution. please check and let me know

Comment: Thanks, it works! I will try to fully understand how everything is working and then hopefully I can manage to do a similar thing for the other codec components that I'm going to create. I'm going to change the syntax a little, e.g. from `const { mp3EncodingType } = this.props;` to `const mp3EncodingType = this.props.mp3EncodingType` as it's more clear to me this way (I'm new to object destructuring). Is there anything wrong with changing it to my way?